# Double Templated Object

Tags: c++, syntax

I am trying to create a Queue of templated Stacks. But I don't know how to add data or retrieve data from the Queue.

I am initiating it like this:

```
Queue<Stack<Function>> processQueue;
```

with "Function" being a class I created.

For example, I'm trying to figure out how to add things like a function to the top of the first stack in the queue.

I have an enqueue function within the Queue class, and a push function within the Stack class.

I've tried doing it different ways but I can't figure out the proper syntax or even if this is a legal thing to do.
Here's an example:

```
Function newFunc(funcName, funcExecept);
processQueue.enqueue(Stack<Function>(push(newFunc)));
```

Or if I want to retrieve data:

```
processQueue.peekFront().returnTop().getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't valid, as `push` must be on an instantiated object. Create the stack first, then push the Function, then add to queue.

```
Function newFunc(funcName, funcExecept);
Stack<Function> stack;
stack.push( newFunc );
processQueue.enqueue(stack);
```

or, put the stack of the queue first, then push to it

```
processQueue.enqueue(Stack<Function>());
processQueue.peekFront().push( Function( funcName, funcExecept ) );
```

In the second option, using `peekFront` assumes there's only one Stack in the queue, which is the one just added.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to answer with exact syntax when we don't know the interface of your `Queue` and `Stack` classes, but here is how you could do it with the standard `std::queue` and `std::stack`:

```
std::queue<std::stack<Function> processQueue;

// Add function to top of first stack of queue:
Function newFunc(funcName, funcExecept);
if (processQueue.empty())
  processQueue.push({}); // push an empty stack into the queue
processQueue.front().push(newFunc);

// Retrieve data:
processQueue.front().top().getName();
```

The function names will of course be different in your case (based on your class' API), but the principle should be the same.

Note that unless you have a *strong* reason to use custom classes, you should use the standard containers instead; they're way more tested and optimised than custom implementations are ever likely to be.